# How to handle future undefined in angular2

Tags: angular

In my angular2 application, I have an object `serviceData` which value will be set in future from rest/http call. When I try to display them in my html view, I am getting `undefined` error.

I have defined `serviceData` but not `serviceData.success`, so the `serviceData.success` is undefined.

Is there a way I can avoid that error so `serviceData.success` will be displayed once it is available? Here's my **template**:

```
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.success}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.messages}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.sessionId}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.firstName}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.lastName}}</li>
```

**Component**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

//Component code
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

})
export class AppComponent {

  private serviceData: any;

}
```

Comment: well, there is a lot of possible solutions, but maybe the simpler of them is initialize the object with empty values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `*ngIf` directive to add element to DOM only after `serviceData` variable gets some values, like this:

```
<div *ngIf="serviceData">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.success}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.messages}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.sessionId}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.firstName}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData.lastName}}</li>
</div>
```

While `serviceData` is `undefined`, this `div` won't be added to DOM, it will be added only after `serviceData` is filled with some values.

You can also use Elvis operator (`?`):

```
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData?.success}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData?.messages}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData?.sessionId}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData?.firstName}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">{{serviceData?.lastName}}</li>
```

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Go ahead, let me know what you have achieved. I'd just add that in order for `*ngIf` directive to work, `serviceData` has to be undefined before you get data from your rest call, so just declare it, don't assign value to it: `serviceData: any;`

Comment: I used the second option {{serviceData?.success}} and it worked for me. Thanks @Stefan Svrkota